# How to generate Certificate AWS (ACM)

Tags: https, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, ovh, aws-acm

I am currently in the process of migrating my app from Heroku to AWS ECS. I am at the stage where I want to establish a secure connection by enabling https for my app. From what I understand, I need a certificate, which I can obtain using the AWS ACM.

I tried to generate a certificate by providing the currently active production domain name used on my app hosted on Heroku. I purchased this domain name from OVH.

However, the response from AWS was very delayed, and I ultimately found out that my certificate request had failed.

Can you assist me ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we cannot directly attach a certificate issued from AWS ACM to AWS ECS, one way would be to use AWS ALB in front of the AWS ECS. The AWS ACM-issued certificate can then be attached to AWS ALB.

Secondly, for AWS ACM to issue a certificate the domain needs to be publicly resolvable (*resolvable on the internet*) and we will have to add a CNAME record to prove the domain ownership (*DNS Validation*). If these conditions are met, the certificate will be issued by AWS-ACM.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I expressed myself poorly and I understood the first point you mentioned.

For the second point, where should I add the CNAME record to prove domain ownership ? Is it on Route 53 ?

Comment: You will have to add the CNAME record where you have the domain hosted. Are you using Route 53 for hosting the domain?

Comment: The domain name is hosted on OVH, and I'm not using Route 53.
If I understand correctly, I need to add the CNAME record that I see in the certificate details on OVH for AWS to validate my certificate ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.